# Use color map from .tif.aux.xml from ArcGIS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, colormap

I have a raster file (.tif) of different ecosystem types (from natureserve). Each value corresponds to a different type. I'm trying to get a table of those attributes and colors. The file includes (what looks like) an attribute table with a color map in a .tif.aux.xml file.

Opening the xml file in a text editor shows entries such as: GDALRasterAttributeTable tableType="thematic". and then rows and rows of the different raster values and their attributes.

How can I open this in QGIS or convert it to a format I can use?

Comment: QGIS does not handle rsater attribute tables (https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/32803/2856). You might be able to adapt some old python code I wrote years ago to write out to a CSV file - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/84729/2856